# Removing carriage returns from a mail merge field in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge, carriage-return

I have a mail merge field called, `«ADDRESSLINE2»`

My data is bad how do remove the carriage return from this merge field.

Comment: If the carriage return is in the data, in the general case you will not be able to remove it using field codes. What is the data source (Word, Excel, Access,...)?

Comment: Up vote this question if you found it useful please :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean when that field is populated during mail merge but has no data a line break still remains in the document? Microsoft has a [tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/264723) about how to avoid this.

> On the Tools menu, click Mail Merge. In the Mail Merge Helper dialog
>   box, click Merge.
>
> NOTE: You must select the main document and data source for the merge
>   before you perform step 2. In the Merge dialog box, under When Merging
>   Records, click either: Don't print blank lines when data fields are
>   empty.
>
> -or- Print blank lines when data fields are empty. Click Close in the Merge dialog box, and then click Close in the Mail Merge Helper.
>
> NOTE: If you made no changes in the Merge dialog box, the Close button
>   is not available. Click Cancel instead.

Answer (score 0):

click either: Don't print blank lines when data fields are empty.

-or- Print blank lines when data fields are empty

WAT